# Java Application Servers alternatives

Tags: java, jboss, weblogic, application-server, jboss6.x

I've been professionally working with Java application servers for five years, but I have only experienced my self two vendors: Weblogic and JBoss, and mainly the last.

Focusing in **JBoss** I'm currently migrating (or at least trying to) some apps from 4.2.2 version to the first "stable" version of 6.x series. However I feel cluttered with issues far more complicated that I expected. Class loading, logging, startup process, everything seams to have changed, I'm sure for better but will always be like this?

So I question myself **what are the other real alternatives out there**? The existing alternatives have the same problems?

You may ask what features do I use for requiring a application server like JBoss: currently JMS, XA Transactions, Datasources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many of the features of full-blown applications servers are provided individually, and can be bundled with simpler alternatives like Tomcat or Jetty. JMS has [multiple implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service#Provider_implementations), like ActiveMQ, HornetQ, etc. [Same goes for JTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Transaction_API#Opensource_JTA_implementations).

Spring is a nice alternative to JavaEE in that regard - it can run on a simple Tomcat and supports datasources, [JTA](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2007/jw-04-xa.html) and messaging. SprignSource also develops the tc server, which is a "enterprise-like" tomcat.

(I noticed you omitted Glasfish from the list - it is an application server worth taking a look at.)

Comment: Your mileage may vary, but adding all of the features an application server has to a servlet container doesn't necessarily result in a simpler solution. Adding stuff like JPA, JTA and JMS separately means a lot of extra overhead in getting the stuff configured, working together and updated at your side.